# custom PostgreSQL query execute to django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7

i have two models with relationship one to many in django app using app using postgres/postgis database.
i have create one not easy query in database and pgadmin panel  and works correct.

here the query :

```
select string_agg(distinct app_work.id::text, ', ') AS code_work,string_agg(distinct app_work.stage, ', ') 
AS stage,string_agg(distinct app_work.dfield_work, ', ') AS dfield,app_point.geom  
from app_point, app_work where app_point.id=app_work.point_field_id GROUP BY app_point.id;
```

now i want to use this query(i need that results from this query) in my django app to create a geojson or json export.
i am not sure how convert this query using django method objects and queries(like `point.objects.all()`) i try to use custom postgres query like this :

models.py

```
class point(models.Model):
    geom = models.MultiPointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class meta:
        verbose_name_plural="point_info"


class work(models.Model):
        dfield_work = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    point_field= models.ForeignKey('point', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

vews.py

```
from django.db import connection


def points(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""seselect string_agg(distinct app_work.id::text, ', ') AS code_work,string_agg(distinct app_work.stage, ', ') 
AS stage,string_agg(distinct app_work.dfield_work, ', ') AS dfield,app_point.geom  
from app_point, app_work where app_point.id=app_work.point_field_id GROUP BY app_point.id from log_point, log_work where log_point.id=log_work.point_field_id GROUP BY log_point.id""")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    print row
    data = serialize('geojson', row)
    return HttpResponse(data,content_type='json')
```

in the print row i take a correct list results

but not working and  i have this error :

```
'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: what line is that error from?

Comment: @HenryWoody that error show me in the page from the browser if I visit this link.any idea ?

Comment: I think there should still be a traceback with the error even in the browser, but if not can you include the traceback from the console/terminal that's running your server?

Comment: Also where is `serialize` defined?

Comment: Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\serializers\geojson.py in start_object, line 35


if that help you I use this code in views.py

Comment: Is `row` already in the format you want (minus labels)?

Comment: @HenryWoody is a list I want a geojson for this reasn I use this code line  `serialize('geojson', row)` in other case if I use `serialize('geojson', point.objects.all())` then work,but I need results from query,any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The Django geojson `serialize` method expects a queryset (as can be seen from usage [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/)) rather than a tuple. From the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8ef8bc0f64c463684268a7c55f3d3da4de066c0d/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py), we can see that the `Serializer(JSONSerializer)` class is designed to "Convert a queryset to GeoJSON" and expects objects that it can call `._meta` on (i.e. Django models). Thus when you pass a tuple (the output of `cursor.fetchall()`) to `serialize` you get the error `'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

Since you are using a raw SQL query there is really no need to use the geojson serializer as it's designed to convert Python objects to JSON. You can instead convert the output of your SQL query to JSON and send that as the response.

Here is an example:

```
import json
from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse


query_text = """
SELECT
    string_agg(distinct app_work.id::text, ', ') AS code_work,
    string_agg(distinct app_work.stage, ', ') AS stage,
    string_agg(distinct app_work.dfield_work, ', ') AS dfield,
    app_point.geom
FROM
    app_point, app_work
WHERE
    app_point.id = app_work.point_field_id
GROUP BY
    app_point.id;
"""

def points(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query_text)
        data = dictfetchall(cursor)

    stringified_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(stringified_data, content_type="application/json")


def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

(`dictfetchall` from the the [Django SQL docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly))

A couple things to note in the above code:

1. This is fairly important: using a `with` for the `cursor` so that the connection is closed when we are done querying the database. You can also close the connection manually, but the `with` statement handles it for us.
2. Using the `dictfetchall` function, we convert the output of the SQL query to a Python dictionary (ready to become JSON). There is no need to use the Django serializer since we are using raw Python datatypes instead of Python Objects or Django Models.

Comment: not I take this error `In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False` in browser. in the line `return JsonResponse(data) `

Comment: @Mar oh right, since `data` will be a list, not a dictionary you will have to set `safe=False` I'll update.

Comment: @Mar Actually changed to `HttpResponse` but calling `json.dumps` before sending. The `safe=False` flag is a little spooky

Comment: you are amazing look to work,but its not geojson but a simple json

Comment: @Mar what database are you using?

Comment: I use postgres/PostGIS database that json don't recognizes geometry fields epsg.

Comment: @Mar I have an idea, wana jump on chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190063/discussion-between-mar-and-henry-woody

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT "id", "LchMatchedTradeRef", "abc" from operation_091 
    UNION 
    SELECT "id", "LchMatchedTradeRef", '' abc FROM operation_084
```

when you need to run this query in your Django app,
you need to follow like bellow.

```
    empty_var = "''"
    raw_query = 'SELECT "id", "LchMatchedTradeRef", "abc" FROM operation_091 UNION SELECT "id", "LchMatchedTradeRef", ' + empty_var + ' abc FROM operation_084'

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(raw_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor.execute(raw_query) to execute query on django application.

```
sample_query = 'SELET COUNT(*) FROM operation_084'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sample_query)
```